# I get an opencv error when I change the python's version to 3.7.9

Tags: python, opencv, nvidia-jetson-nano

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
dispW=640
dispH=480
flip=2
camSet='nvarguscamerasrc !  video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=3264, height=2464, format=NV12, framerate=21/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method='+str(flip)+' ! video/x-raw, width='+str(dispW)+', height='+str(dispH)+', format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink'
cam= cv2.VideoCapture(camSet)
face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/ppp/Desktop/test/cascade/face.xml')
while True:
   ret, frame = cam.read()
   gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
   for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
       cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
   cv2.imshow('nanoCam',frame)
   cv2.moveWindow('nanoCam',0,0)
   if cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q'):
       break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i'm using jetson nano with pi camera at codeOSS.

on python3 3.6.9, this code works very well but on change into 3.7.9,it occurs error.

**OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): nvarguscamerasrc ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=3264, height=2464, format=NV12, framerate=21/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink in function 'icvExtractPattern' Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/ppp/Desktop/test/test2.py", line 14, in  gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'**
​

and then i tried to change into

`cam= cv2.VideoCapture(0)`

it occurs again

but on cmd i tried to

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 nvarguscamerasrc sensor_mode=0 ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),width=3820, height=2464, framerate=21/1, format=NV12' ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! 'video/x-raw,width=960, height=616' ! nvvidconv ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink -e
```

but it works every python version.

how could i try

Comment: it seems it is using  OpenCV(4.6.0). Are you sure its 3.7.9 ?

Comment: yes, but i tried to change python 3.9.3 and make it 3.7.9 again. Does opencv 4.6.0 not match with python 3.7.9?

Comment: its up to how you installed be carefull about the version

Comment: i remember that ``` sudo apt-get install python3-opencv```. and i wanted to remove or uninstall opencv and reinstall, nothing works :(

Comment: Then remove by using the command `sudo pip uninstall opencv` and then install a specified version with the command: `pip install opencv-python==3.7.9`